# How to set a Quick Launch page so that only a group can see it in SharePoint (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, quick-launch, audience-targeting

I'm currently in the process of writing an inventory page. I need it to be available on the Quick launch panel but to only be visible to a group of users I've created.

This is the current Quick launch at the top of the site. I've blurred the other tabs for security purposes.

[image: This is the current Quick launch at the top of the site. I've blurred the other tabs for security purposes.]

I've found limiting it to where only the group I've assigned can see the contents of the page will work but I need to have it hidden from those who don't have access.

Does anyone have experience in hiding these types of things?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **audience targeting** feature in SharePoint online modern experience to target navigation links to specific groups.

You can target up to 10 Microsoft 365 groups or security groups.

Check this documentation for detailed information: [Target navigation, news, files, links, and web parts to specific audiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-files-links-and-web-parts-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

---

**Note**: If you've selected an audience group that you recently created or changed, it may take some time to see targeting applied for that group.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Here is my group and group members

[image]

2.Navigation to the site collection as a site admin

3.Click "**Edit**" on the Top Navigation bar

[image]

4.On the Edit navigation panel, please turn on "**Enable site navigation audience targeting**" option.

5.Then, click **Edit**

[image]

6.On the Edit windows, enter the group name to the "**Audience to target**" textbox

[image]

7.Users who are not in this group will not see the quick link in the Top Navigation bar. In my test, Jone can not see "Inventory" on the Top Navigation bar.

[image]

For more information, please see "**[Target navigation, news, files, links, and web parts to specific audiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-files-links-and-web-parts-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)**" article.